# failed to create endpoint due to cannot auto create comptenent activemq

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I'm using apache camel to recieve a message via activeMQ

[Eror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFJqm.png)

my end point

```
<route id="analystaction">
<from uri="activemq:queue:{{mqQueueName}}?testConnectionOnStartup=true"/>
<to uri="file:{{processingpath}}"/>
</route>
```

It should be working as I'm having all the jars needed

I've three jars related to active MQ

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5I4nM.png)

Comment: Can you please include stack trace as a code snippet? It will help others to search if they have similar issue.